# center image inside overflow-hidden-parent

Tags: css

I have an image inside a span tag, the span has a set width and height, and is set to overflow hidden. so it only reveals a small portion of the image. This works but the small portion of the image that is visible is the top left corner. I would like it to be the center of the image that is visible. I think I need to absolutely position the image, but the size of the image can vary though. Does anyone know how to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="lightbox_images">
                <h6>Alternate Views</h6>
                <span>
                    <a href="http://www.kranichs.com/mothers_rings/mothers_rings_txt2.jpg" rel="lightbox[product_alternate_views]" title="This is my captions 1">
                        <img src="http://www.kranichs.com/mothers_rings/mothers_rings_txt2.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a href="https://www.kranichs.com/product_images/Simon-G@346_M_346_M.jpg" rel="lightbox[product_alternate_views]" title="This is my captions 2">
                        <img src="https://www.kranichs.com/product_images/Simon-G@346_M_346_M.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a href="http://www.kranichs.com/images/simong/sim_banner_01.jpg" rel="lightbox[product_alternate_views]" title="This is my captions 3">
                        <img src="http://www.kranichs.com/images/simong/sim_banner_01.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a href="http://www.kranichs.com/images/psu/psu_banner.jpg" rel="lightbox[product_alternate_views]" title="This is my captions 4">
                        <img src="http://www.kranichs.com/images/psu/psu_banner.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.lightbox_images{
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
    border:1px solid #F0F0F0;
}
.lightbox_images h6{
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0px;
}
.lightbox_images span{
    padding:5px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
.lightbox_images a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.lightbox_images a img{
    position:absolute;
    left:-50%;
    top:-50%;
}

.lightbox_images span:hover{
    border:1px solid #BBB;
    background-color:#CFCFCF;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given this sort of HTML:

```
<span><img src="..." width="..." height="..." alt="..." /></span>
```

You could use CSS like this:

```
span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;  /* Change this */
  height: 50px; /* Change this */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
span img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px; /* Change this */
  top: -10px;  /* Change this */
}
```

You can then center the image based on its exact dimensions.

Alternatively, if you're able to modify the HTML, you could instead use something like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="...">[name of picture]</a>
</div>
```

Then, match it with this CSS:

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent url(...) center center no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999em; /* Hides the link text */
}
```

In this case, the background will be automatically centered regardless of its dimensions, and it'll still be clickable.

Comment: Thanks, but the image size can very. I tried using -50% but that just makes it -50% of the container width, not the image width.

Comment: I've added an alternative method that can handle images of various dimensions, though it's only useful if you have control over the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, setting the image as the background center, did th trick!

Comment: I noticed that in ie6 now they are not displaying.

Answer (score 28):

As proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837947/2227298 by Billy Moat, there is a solution **without knowing the image height and width.**

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/LSKRy/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zvTnqSbUAk8/Tm49IrDAVCI/AAAAAAAACv8/05Ood5LcjkE/s1600/Ferrari-458-Italia-Nighthawk-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution because of dynamic width/height and relative positioning.

Comment: I enjoy this solution, but the use of `display: inline-block` on `.inner` causes a strip of whitespace to be seen when `.outer` has a background. Use `display: table` on both `.inner` and `img` to avoid this problem. (Note: `display: block` on .`inner` will break the effect, but you can use `display: block` on `img` if you want.). Here is a fiddle showing the comparison with yours: http://jsfiddle.net/gfullam/fsowennr/

Comment: Anyone else confused about these negative left & right shifts?

Answer (score 4):

**This example, the images are at the center of the element, regardless of its size**

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="example.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

div.box > img{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    position: relative;
    width: auto !important;
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the width and height of the image varies, I think the only way to do this is with javascript.

Style the image to left:50%; top:50%; and then, use javascript (image onload event maybe) to add margin-left:-*imageWidth*/2 px; margin-top:-*imageHeight*/2 px;

So basically you have

```
span img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

and the following js

```
window.onload = function() {

  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  for(i=0; i<images.length; i++)
     images[i].onload = centerImage(images[i]);


  function centerImage(img) {
    img.style.marginLeft = -(img.width/2) + "px";
    img.style.marginTop = -(img.height/2) + "px";
  }

}
```

PS. If you're using a javascript framework/library the code could simplify a bit, but I didn't make that assumption.

Comment: +1 for "f the width and height of the image varies, I think the only way to do this is with javascript."

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image as the background of the element and set x,y axis as in the following example:

```
#mySpan {
  background-image: url(myimage.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: -10 -10
}
```